# Compose functions/operators with RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs5

Is there any way how to compose functions with RxJS without dot notation.

Use case: My stream of event may be processed by configurable functions and I want to configure them just by adding to the array.

```
const result$ = source$.map(function1).map(function2).map(function3)
```

I'd like to have `farray = [function1, function2, function3]` and use it as follows:

```
const result$ = source$.compose(farray)
```

The reason is that it should be able to change the `farray` during execution (or during init).

I found [transducers-js](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js) but not sure how it's `map` and `filter` and other play with Rx counterparts.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use Rambda.compose with map.

```js
const functions = [x => x * 2, x => x + 1]

Rx.Observable
  .range(0, 10)
  .map(R.compose(...functions))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.21.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Or You can create your own operator:

```js
const functions = [x => x * 2, x => x + 1];

Rx.Observable.prototype.mapCompose = function (functions) {
  return this.map(R.compose(...functions));
};

Rx.Observable
  .range(0, 10)
  .mapCompose(functions)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.21.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Ofc, Rambda compose can be switched for any other compose implementation.

Edit:
Composing Rx operators is a little bit more complicated. It is hard to imagine how it would look like, not to mention implementing it. But you can always compose (or apply) some functions that take observable and return observable. Here is example implementation.

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.apply = function (functions) {
  functions = [].concat(functions);
  
  return functions.reduce(function (observable, func) {
    return func(observable);
  }, this);
};

var functions = [obs => obs.map(x => x*2), obs => obs.filter(x => x % 3 === 0)];

Rx.Observable
  .range(0, 15)
  .apply(functions)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @sielakos. I suppose to write my own compose, pulling Ramda just for this is maybe a little bit overhead. Is there any possibility to compose the even the Rx operators? Like of `.map(fn1)`, `.do(fn2)` and `.filter(fn3)`?

Comment: @DavidC Yeah, you can easily implement good enough compose with reduce. As for composing operators it would be rather hard thing to do, because it is even hard to imagine correct syntax, not to mention implementation. But you can easily compose functions that take and return observables. I added another example to my answer showing just that.